# error when converting string value entered to double,is there the better way other than this?

Tags: c#, input

```cs
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int qty;
            double price;

            Console.WriteLine("please enter the qty");
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("please enter the price ");
            price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            double total = price * qty;
            Console.WriteLine($"tota is : {total:c}");

            Console.ReadKey();  
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

*please enter the qty*

3

*please enter the price*

12.44

**error message after entering double: 12.44**

```console
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   at ConsoleApp1.program.Main() in C:\Users\Baba\Desktop\C#\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 14
```

Comment: The program works just fine. The decimal point depends on your regional settings. I've entered 12.44 and 12,44 and both work just fine

Comment: @PaulSinnema it is working perfect with 12,44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! In addition to @PaulSinnema 's input: you could try `TryParse()` to detect/ avoid invalid user input:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int qty;
            //double price;

            Console.WriteLine("please enter the qty");
            //qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out int qty))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"invalid input \"{input}\"");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("please enter the price ");
            //price = Convert.ToDouble(input);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!double.TryParse(input, out double price))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"invalid input \"{input}\"");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            double total = price * qty;
            Console.WriteLine($"total is : {total:c}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The Windows "Region" / "Customize Format" dialog]